# Looping new objects in Java and passing values from getMethods?

Tags: java, loops

I want to know how I can loop a new object within the same class, so that I can repeat the code to have several different objects with different details entered via the Scanner class.

It will probably make sense if I show what I am trying to do:

```
public class Students
{
    private String studFirstName;       // Student's first name
    private String studSurname;         // Student's surname
    private String courseName;          // Course name

    public Students(String sFirstName, String sSurname, String cName)
    {
        studFirstName = sFirstName;
        studSurname = sSurname;
        courseName = cName;
    }

    public String getStudFirstName()                            // Getter for student's first name
    {
        System.out.println("Enter in student's first name: ");  // Prompts end user for input

        Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);                    // Creating a new object
        studFirstName = In.next();                              // Accepts a one word input only

        return studFirstName;
    }

    public String setStudFirstName(String sFirstName)           // Setter for student's first name
    {
        return studFirstName;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        Students first[] = new Students[5]; 

        for(Students a : first)
        {
        }

       Students first[] = new Students("", "", ""); 

       String studFirstName = first.getStudFirstName();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Students first[] = new Students("", "", "");` is not valid syntax. And `set` methods should actually be `void` and set a value, not return it.

Comment: Also a sidenote but you should rather call your class `Student` instead of `Students` since it represents a single student. Using the plural can be somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need a regular for loop in order to assign values within the array.

```
int numStudents = 5;
Student students[] = new Student[numStudents];   // creates an array of 5 nulls

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter your first name: "); // Prompt
    String fname = scan.nextLine();   // Read
    Student s = new Student(fname);   // Assign
    first[i] = s;                     // Store
}
```

You really don't need the get methods since you have access to set the values in the constuctor.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should take a look at [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)). A getter is not meant to take user input. Getter should return the value of a private field. Setters should set the value of a private field.

```
// This is a field
private String myField;

// This will return the current value for the field 'myField'
public String getMyField() {
    return this.myField;
}

// This will asign a new value to the field 'myField'
public void setMyField(String myField) {
     this.myField = myField;
}
```

**Answer**

You will need a regular for loop to create as many students a you want. I renamed your class 'Students' to Student to fit javas naming conventions.

```
int numberOfStudents = 3;
// create an array that can hold up to 3 students
Student[] students = new Stundent[numberOfStudents];
// create the Scanner to read from console.
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// create the 3 students and store them in the array
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    // read the next line from the console
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    // ...
    // if you have anything you need to create the student object (e.g. name, and so on).
    Student s = new Student(name, .....);
    students[i] = s; // store the student object in the array.
}
// you should evt. close the scanner
// scanner.close();
// you can now do anything with your 3 stored students.
System.out.println("The Students first name is: " + students[0].getStudFirstName());
```

Comment: I tried this and I am getting an error of a non static variable not being able to be used in a static context. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you got to wrap this inside your main method. also this code includes placeholders, so it wont work if u copy paste it.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;       // Pre-defined library, contains the Scanner Class

public class Student
{

    // This is a field
    private String studFirstName;

    // This will return the current value for the field 'myField'
    public String getStudFirstName() {
    return this.studFirstName;
    }

    // This will asign a new value to the field 'myField'
    public void setStudFirstName(String studFirstName) {
     this.studFirstName = studFirstName;
    }

    public static void main (String [] agrv)
    {

Comment: I will try re writing it

Comment: You should post what error is present. I also told you that this code wont work as is. It is meant to educate yourself or give some hints and needs some edits to actually compile.

Comment: I realise that, and I did say what error I was getting 'a non static variable not being able to be used in a static context'.

Comment: 'a non static variable' can be everything. you need to be more specific. maybe the line of code in that the error is happening,...

Answer (score 0):

```
        int numberOfStudents = 3;
        // create an array that can hold up to 3 students
        Student[] students = new Student[numberOfStudents];
        // create the Scanner to read from console.
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // create the 3 students and store them in the array
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            // read the next line from the console
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            // ...
            // if you have anything you need to create the student object (e.g. name, and so on).
            Student s = new Student(studFirstName);
            students[i] = s; // store the student object in the array.
        }


    // you should evt. close the scanner
    // scanner.close();
    // you can now do anything with your 3 stored students.
    System.out.println("The Students first name is: " + students[0].getStudFirstName());
}
```

}